# PostgreSQL - Invoking SQL function while doing CREATE OR REPLACE on it

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase, amazon-aurora, high-availability

I have a Postgres 14.4 cluster (AWS Aurora) to which I connect from my application using JDBC.

I use liquibase for schema management - not only tables, but also a bunch of SQL stored procedures and functions. Basically, there is one liquibase changeSet that runs last and executes a set of SQL files which contain stored procedures and functions.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo(arg1 text, arg2 text) LANGUAGE "plpgsql" AS '
BEGIN
   // procedure body
END;
';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bar(arg1 text, arg2 text) RETURNS record LANGUAGE "plpgsql" AS '
BEGIN
   // function body
END;
';
```

These functions / procedures are replaced ONLY when there is a change in one / more SQL files which are part of this changeSet. (`runOnChange: true`).

Whenever I do a rolling deployment of my application (say, with a change in the function body of `bar()`), liquibase will execute the `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bar()` as part of a transaction.

In the few milliseconds while `bar()` is being replaced, there are other ongoing transactions (from other replicas of my application) which are **continuously trying to invoke `bar()`**.

Only in this tiny time window, few transactions fail with the following error:

```
ERROR: function bar(arg1 => text, arg2 => text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 4 : errorCode = 42883
```

I don't want any of these transactions to fail (we do not have any proper way of re-trying them from the application layer). This is seen as affecting availability. However, it is acceptable for these transactions to **BLOCK** (for a few hundred ms) while the SQL function body is being replaced, and then proceed with invocation.

Is there a way to safely modify a stored function / procedure in PostgreSQL while that function / procedure is being invoked continuously by multiple transactions?

Answer (score 1):

So, I actually posted this question in [pgsql-general](https://mailto:pgsql-general@postgresql.org) mailing list, and received a useful insight which saved my day.

Tracking it here for posterity.

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION should be atomic and cannot change the function
> signature.  I don't see how a function cannot exist at some point in this case.

> Are you sure that Liquibase is not dropping the function before re-creating it?
> If Liquibase drops and re-creates the function in separate transactions, the
> transactions trying to execute that function may find it dropped when using the
> read committed isolation level.

Turns out, it was indeed liquibase which was:

- dropping the functions in one transaction (inadvertently as the result of a `DROP TYPE CASCADE`)
- immediately followed by the next transaction which did a `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` which re-created these functions

The tiny gap in time after the first transaction commit, before the second transaction could commit was when the function actually ceased to exist.
So, the invocations during that time failed.

See [discussion on postgres mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/2095430749.1191808.1683147795554%40office.mailbox.org#86b73d980aae92af310115ede7681ec1)